# how to archive old data in database with many table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, odoo

I have a database on postgreSQL in odoo. I want to remove the old data to solve the problem of slowness and restore it when necessary. Need advice please.

Comment: make an archive db?

Answer (score 0):

You can make pg_dump to save it to external file, and then pg_restore in the future. You can read about pg dump and restore in documentation: [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html). There are some nice examples how to use this command.